# Is it still considered bad practice not to separate header from implementation?

Tags: c++, c, header

Almost every language other than C and C++ doesn't separate headers from implementation. Is it still considered a bad practice to put the implementation of the functions/methods in the header file so you don't need to separate the two?

Example:

```
// File: myUtilLib.hpp

void myFunc1() {
  doSomething...
}

void myFunc2() {
  doSomething else...
}
```

Instead to have to copy/paste all the declaration in a separate `.cpp` file ?

Comment: Almost every other language doesn't have a slow header inclusion system. I personally can't wait until modules get sorted out. And then there's that you can actually hide the implementation when it's not right there in the header.

Comment: The biggest cons are the slower compilation times and violation of one-definition rule (which can be overridden with `inline` keyword).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Header-only libraries are not considered "bad" practice or "good" practices, they're a design decision that you as a writer have to consider with both its pros and cons. Multiple libraries do use the header-only approach and they're widely used in the industry such as Boost.

This is done with a combination of writing the `inline` (or `constexpr`, which are implicitly inline) keyword before the function definition to override the one-definition rule which states that two files cannot include the same symbol during compilation due to linker errors. This leads to "excessive inlining" despite the fact that the `inline` keyword does not actually *force* inlining. Classes and their methods are also implicitly inline (if you define them in the header), so having to put the keyword on those is unnecessary.

There are obvious drawbacks to the header-only approach, the most obvious being the increased compile times and the fact that you have multiple definitions of your code running about. However the easiest pro would be that you can just plop the header and it'll be easier to set up for you and possibly the user. It's a design decision that you have to take upon yourself.

Do note however that there are cases where header-only approach is the *only* approach, and this is in regards to templated code. There is a proposal for C++ to finally get [modules](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/modules-update-on-work-in-progress-doug-gregor) that promises to make the build system less painful. However it hasn't been fully accepted but progress on it seems to be high on the importance scale.

Answer (score 3):

There are several aspects on this.

First, the function HAS to be `inline` or only included once in the whole program, or you will get errors. And if the function is large, and the compiler decides to make an "out of line" copy, it may still be included more than once in the main executable, causing larger than necessary code.

Second, compile tile suffers if you keep doing this, because the same function is compiled multiple times.

Third, if the functions are quite large, and they are member functions, included within the class definition, then it becomes hard to get a good overview of the class content.

On the other hand, it's quite convenient to have all the stuff in one place, so there's an argument for still persevering, despite the above drawbacks. However, I don't personally think that it is enough of a benefit. Eventually, the files get large enough that they are unwieldy anyway, so you start splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the implementation in the header isn't just bad practice, it doesn't work in most cases.

(Unless all your functions are defined as `inline`, but that's an unusual case.)

If more than one `.cpp` file has a `#include` for your header, you're going to have link-time errors due to multiple definitions of `myFunc1` and `myFunc2`.

Comment: Uh.. not if it's written as `inline`. Header-only libraries do exist, and they do work. So -1.

Comment: @yes123, That's not the problem with the ODR. Each TU gets its own copy.

Comment: Not only does each TU get its own copy, but the entire program ends up with several copies of otherwise identical code that even a smart linker probably won't clean up.

Comment: @yes123: Macros in general aren't going to solve the problem. Except for `inline` functions, you need to have exactly one definition of each function in your entire program (which can consist of multiple source files). But you want one consistent copy of the *declaration* in each translation unit (source file) that uses the function. The way to do that is to put your function definitions in `.c` or `.cpp` files, and declare them in `.h` files with [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: Sometimes should be yes, sometimes should be no. Say yes: Commonly you should separate header from implementation because of multiple definitions as @KeithThompson said. Say no: If you write c++ template, you should not separate header from implementation, because a lot of compilers have not `export` keyword.

Comment: @KaiWen Not only do they not have it, but it's removed from the standard as of C++11 so header-only is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Rapptz Yes, I agree.